# How to disable all the resident apps and services I don't use?

Tags: services, autostart, tweak

Once I open the system monitor I can immediately notice a number of processes I am sure I make zero use of: avahi-daemon, evolution-addressbook-factory and 5 more evolution processes (taking 116 megabytes together), zeitgeist-daemon (and 2 other zeitgeist processes). Perhaps many other processes are useless for me too but I just don't know what they do so I prefer not to mess with them so far. Can I just stop them from starting at the boot time (something like the way it's done in Windows - one can just disable unneeded services easily there) or is there an application that can check for their presence and terminate them after the boot process completes perhaps?

Comment: Can you tell us how to invoke the Ubuntu "system monitor" in GUI or terminal? Or if not base Ubuntu can you provide the `sudo apt install Xxxxx"? I'd like to see these processes to understand the question better.

Comment: I mean `gnome-system-monitor`, @WinEunuuchs2Unix I also believe all sorts of `top`, `htop` etc can provide the same information.

Comment: Check your "Startup Applications" for the first place to safely remove stuff you don't use.

Comment: The unneeded stuff I've mentioned is not there, @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: You would have to research each process on it's own to see what it does and what depends on it.